# Solaris 9 - Set project max-shm-memory for Sybase

Tags: project, solaris, sap-ase, mode

When using Solaris 10, I use to execute `projmod –s –K “project.max-shm-memory=(privileged,4G,deny)” ‘user.sybase’` before installing Sybase.

Now I am using Solaris 9 and the command is different, it doesn't know the option `-s -K`.

Could you please help me to find what I need to do/execute to change this project parameter on Solaris 9?

Thank you for your help

Comment: The problem may be moot.  What version of Sybase?  Will what you have even run on Solaris 9?

Comment: I am installing Sybase 12.5.4 on `Solaris 9 9/05 HW s9s_u9wos_06b SPARC`. Think like I can have the answer here: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.dc35889_1254/html/installsol/X30291.htm

Answer (score 1):

It's my understanding that for Solaris 9, you must edit the `/etc/system` file and  `shmsys:shminfo_shmmax=size.of.share.memory` which is  the equivalent `max-shm-memory` in Solaris 10.

Let me know if that helps.